# Product Display - Can I redirect the page when selecting a product from the drop down on a product reference field w/ unlimited values?

Tags: 7, commerce

When creating a product display, you can select an unlimited number of values on the product reference field. This adds the drop down menu that will load the different products when selecting them via ajax. The issue I am running into is I would like the page to redirect to those items when selecting them.

I have a related products view and a bill of materials view beneath the product display that depend on the contextual filter of the NID of the content on that page. (I think having a related products view plus multiple items on the product reference field is redundant, but it is what the client wants). Those views don't refresh when the product reference drop down is changed because the page never refreshes, so the NID of the page is still the same. I notice only the items that are attached to the product itself change via ajax such as the price, which does make sense since you are only grabbing the products via the product reference field, not the product display.

Is there any way to somehow redirect the page when the product reference field drop down is changed to a different product?  I feel like this can't be done since you are only grabbing the product information there, not the product display information. The product itself doesn't know if it is part of a display or not and I feel that is what the issue is.

If anyone has any suggestions or ideas they would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.